# PanResponder behavior changes when wrapped in flex View

Tags: css, react-native, expo

I'm using expo to build a cross platform application (android, iOS and web) and I've noticed some strange behavior that I can't fix and I don't really know is this is expected or not.

```
Expo Version: 40.0.0
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): all
```

I am creating a component that allow me to create drap and drop components from an alphabet. For each element of the alphabet, it create a “draggable” view. It used to work pretty fine until I wrapped those component in a View with the following properties:

```html
<View
      style={{
        flex: 5,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      }}>
```

As a consequence, I can only drag the components on the X axis on both Android and iOS (tested on a virtual device as well as on a real device), everything works fine on the browser.
Even stranger, the actual position stored in the state is actually correct, only the visual seems to be affected by that (when I attach a dropped event on the drag, it's the position of the finger that is passed, as expected, and not the position of the visual element)

I’ve created a Snack available here: https://snack.expo.io/dNPUnq4SR (the code was simplified the code to work with an alphabet of size 3).
The behavior can be seen by commenting line 117 of the `components/LetterSlide.tsx` file, and opening the result in an Android device.

I don’t know how to solve this issue and I’m not sure if the correct behavior is the browser’s or the devices.

Comment: This appears to be related to how `flexWrap: wrap` enforces positioning. If I remove that rule, it works fine

Comment: Indeed, removing this properties seems to fix this issue, so I guess I'll have to deal with wrapping manually and find a workaround.

Do you happen to know if this is documented/expected or not ? (as it does not happens on the web version, I assume this is react-native related).

Comment: I can't find any real info about it, but it may have something to do with the underlying limitations of how the Yoga engine is implemented